# getjson not running the console.log in chrome

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out why my code is not giving me anything in console.log.  The code is below.  If I set a watch on the data variable, I can see the value, but nothing ever outputs to console.  Even if I just have console.log("test"), that doesn't either.  Just curious why that is?

```
 $.getJSON("load.json")
     .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
     });
```

Here is my json:

```
{"step1": {"stepID": "1", "stepValue": "John Doe", "stepType": "1", "topValue": "350", leftValeu:'350'}, step2: {stepID: "2","stepValue": "John Doe","stepType": "2","topValue":"50","leftValeu":"150"}}
```

Comment: the json as is is invalid. did you even try it in any other browsers before tagging this as a chrome problem?

Comment: @KrishR if the done isn't called, the success won't be either (they are one and the same)

Comment: Yes I agreed, his Json is invalid

Comment: Oh can you tell me where my json is wrong?

Comment: @chuckw87 http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You have keys that are not wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the syntax in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) you can see that there is a second parameter that is needed with $.getJSON. Run a function as the second parameter and then after that function is closed you can run .done, .fail, and .always.

So for your example above try:

```
$.getJSON("load.json", function(data){ 
     console.log(data);
})
     .done(function(){
          console.log("second success");
     })
     .fail(function(){
          console.log("Failure");
     });
```

Let me know if you have any questions,

Comment: the second parameter is not required, as signified by the `[]` that the parameter is wrapped in.